# powershell works in ise but not in

Tags: powershell

You've got a first time poster long time reader here, so we'll see how I go.

Briefly, I have 3 PS script involved in this:

1. Manager.PS1 = starts auditor
2. Auditor.PS1 = does something, uses Restquery.ps1
3. Restquery.PS1 = utilizes a RestAPI, takes a params: A PSCredential object

The problem I'm having is:

- If I run Auditor.PS1, it collects my creds via the creation of a PSCredential object. When called and provided with the PSCredential object, Restquery.PS1 works fine.
- However, if I run Manager.PS1, which is essentially just running Auditor.PS1, Restquery.PS1 prompts me for creds when its run.

Here is Restquery.PS1 and where the creds are used:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    $global:creds
)

function Get-WSMembers ($global:creds) {
[xml]$return = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $uri -Credential $global:creds -TimeoutSec 120
```

Here is where I'm using it in Auditor.ps1

```
$Instances = Get-WSMembers -creds $creds
```

Here is Manager.ps1 running Auditor.ps1

```
powershell <Script path>\Auditor.ps1
```

Feel like I'm lacking a bit of detail here, trying to remain succinct.

Anyone have any ideas? I assume its going to be a session variable or something I always stuff these up.

Comment: How about posting the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: What happens if you close your ISE session and start over?